# Date parse in powershell

Tags: date, parsing, powershell

1. How to parse the current date to 20150801(expected output) in power shell ?
   Tried using parsing exact but not able to convert.
2. Does power shell supports drag and drop of files. (Ex: i need to drag a file from a path to another application).

Comment: That's two separate questions: please don't try and do both together: it will just lead to confusion.

Comment: "Tried using parsing exact but not able to convert." show the code you attempted with and what error it gave

Comment: Also, your example is ambiguous. Is `20150801` Aug 1st or January 8th?

Comment: I would consider it safe to assume that the output is supposed to be in short ISO date format, making it Aug 1st.

Comment: Yes .. its august 1. !

Answer (score 3):

The current date and time is `Get-Date`. You can pass a `Format` parameter to specify text output in the form you want in the [normal way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Eg.

```
get-date -format 'yyyyMMdd'
```

If you want to format a date you have already in the form of a `[DateTime]` use either:

```
$theDate.ToString('yyyyMMdd')
```

or

```
'{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $theDate.
```

You use the various Parse and ParseExact methods of `DateTime` to convert a string to a `DateTime`, not to convert a `DateTime` to a string.

> Does power shell supports drag and drop of files.

You can write both WinForms and WPF applications in PowerShell (in the latter case via some helpers). There are lots of examples. You need a GUI application to perform drag and drop on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for #2.   Yes it does, with caveats.  First drag and drop requires STA (single threading) mode, secondly on later versions of Windows it also requires non-elevation.  Meaning if you need elevation, you'll need to self-elevate the script after the drop has occurred.

I use this to force STA mode so I don't have to edit my shortcuts.

If ([threading.thread]::CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() -eq "MTA") {
    & C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -sta -WindowStyle Hidden $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
exit

}